How to mock returning a memorystream multiple times?
I have this call to an external source that returns a FileResponse object that also contains a Stream object. To Mock it I use a MemoryStream object and that works as long as the test is focused on one item.
As the products to update can now come from 2 data sources I need to create a unit test that mocks sending 2 items to the external source. I have the following code:
_client.Setup(c => c.ApiSupplierProductPostAsync(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).ReturnsAsync(new FileResponse(200, null, new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(json))), null, null));

The problem I have is that when processing the second product the MemoryStream is at the end of the stream.
How do I get the Setup to return a new MemoryStream every time it is called?
The string given to the method is the json body of the message send to the external source.

You can use a lambda expression: ReturnsAsync(() => new FileResponse(...))
